# How to make images resize instead of text disappearing when there isn't enough space?

Tags: android, android-layout

When the screen is too small to contain all the layout elements at their natural size (say, for example, when a smaller screen goes to landscape mode) I notice that it looks like Android first conceals TextViews, and then shrinks images until they fit. That's my impression, maybe I'm not completely correct. My question is this: is it possible to make it resize images first? That way, the text would still be visible, even if the images need to be made quite small.

Here is one of many examples. The scaleType is irrelevant. From my observations, if Android doesn't have enough room on the screen and needs to decide whether to shrink an image or to crop/hide text... the text will be hurt first.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/large_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerInside" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Show us an XML example we can work with

Comment: Blundell, I should hope the question is simple and straightforward enough, but I added one example. Keep in mind that this is just one simple example... in ANY layout where there is not enough room to show text and the full-size image, the text seems to be pushed out of the way instead of shrinking the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here try this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/large_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scaleType="centerInside" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />



</LinearLayout>
```

That'll get your textview to wrap_content ie not shrink and the ImageView to take up the remaining space, therefore if it starts getting squashed it'll be the ImageView that is squished down.

If your worried about it getting too big, set a `android:maxHeight="200dip"` or something similar

Comment: Excellent! That's exactly what I need. Determining what maxWidth and what maxHeight is appropriate may be a nuisance, but I can live with that. One important gotcha I ran across for anyone else using this: maxHeight and maxWidth only work if android:adjustViewBounds="true"

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers custom view for small screen on landscape mode should fix your problems

Comment: Using a completely different layout for smaller screens, or even programmatically checking screen size vs size of images is certainly one option... but definitely not what I want. I just want something flexible, where images will shrink to fit the layout and preserve text.